# vb.net 2010 Sockets suddenly stopping?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, networking

I am currently creating a multi-client server application in vb.net 2010. I am using sockets and network streams to read the data.

it's hard to explain what is happening and posting code probably won't do much good being the scale of my project. However, i'll just give a run through of what i am doing and then what happens and hopefully someone can help me, or give me some ideas on what could be happening :).

I start up the server and client and they both connect and listen asynchronously. In my client, i put in the login information and send it to the server using the network stream. The server reads everything fine, starts listening again, handles the data, sends account information to client, says the client is connected, and then randomly closes once it's done handling the data and exits the function. While this is happening, the client is receiving the data, starts listening again, handles the data, says the socket is connected, and then once everything is done, randomly closes after the function is done.

Now I have already made sure that other code wasn't affecting the sockets, and commented everything out that wasn't needed and would allow each the server and client to keep looping. (creating a game so there's a serverloop and gameloop) It just seems like it does all the work and then exits out the reading sub, and just stops listening for more to read.

If anyone has any idea's it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The code is the same on each side:

Receiving data:

```
    Private Sub ReceiveOneByte(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim netStream As NetworkStream
    Dim InData() As Byte
    Dim DataLen(3) As Byte
    Dim inLength As Integer
    Dim Buffer As New clsBuffer
    Dim MsgType As Integer
    Dim NewData() As Byte
    Dim Empty() As Byte

    SyncLock Client_TCP.Client
        Try
            netStream = New NetworkStream(Client_TCP.Client)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        ' gets length of data comming in
        Try
            netStream.Read(DataLen, 0, 4)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        inLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(DataLen, 0)

        ' gets data comming in
        ReDim InData(inLength)
        netStream.Read(InData, 0, inLength)
        netStream.Flush()
    End SyncLock

    Buffer.WriteBytes(InData)
    MsgType = Buffer.ReadLong

    If InData.Length > (InData.Length - 4) Then
        ReDim NewData(InData.Length - 5)
        Array.ConstrainedCopy(InData, 4, NewData, 0, NewData.Length - 1)
        HandleDataSub(MsgType)(0, NewData)
    Else
        HandleDataSub(MsgType)(0, Empty)
    End If

    Client_TCP.GetStream.BeginRead(Readbyte, 0, 1, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveOneByte), Nothing)

End Sub
```

To Send Data:

```
    Public Sub Send(ByVal Data() As Byte)
    Dim netStream As NetworkStream
    Dim len As Integer = Data.Length
    Dim DataLen() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(len)
    Dim bit(0) As Byte
    bit(0) = 1
    SyncLock Client_TCP.Client
        netStream = New NetworkStream(Client_TCP.Client)
        netStream.Write(bit, 0, 1)
        netStream.Write(DataLen, 0, 4)
        netStream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
        'netStream.Flush()
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post any of your socket handling code? in particular, so we can see the exits? Which async API are you using? (there are several async socket APIs) Are you checking for socket errors? How are you bundling up the separate messages on the wire, etc? If you are using the newer async API, are you checking the `return` value from the `ReceiveAsync` method? (this is very important)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `IAsyncResult Begin*(...)` pattern, it is ***required*** that you call the `End*(...)` method. This is the place where it will tell you about any problems it had. It is probably trying *really hard* to tell you what the problem is, but you aren't checking. Incidentally, in this particular case this is also where you can check the number of bytes returned - it could be 0 if the stream terminated unexpectedly. So the first thing to add at the top of your method is (pseudocode... ok, who am I kidding... C#):

```
try {
    int bytesRead = Client_TCP.GetStream.EndRead(ar);
    if(bytesRead < 1) {
        // EOF; do something
    } else if(bytesRead == 1) {
        // this is your expected scenario: your code here
    } else {
        // well that's just crazy talk!
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // log this exception; shouldn't throw, because you are on a worker
    // thread here; you *might* want to clean up, though
}
```

This will probably get you started on diagnosing the problem. It should also be noted that this is *not* the most efficient way to use a socket - but it should work, and I don't want to confuse things by start talking about alternative async APIs etc.

Comment: Ok so i used what you gave me and that helped out more. Now the problem i am having is that while it's running through all the working code it sometimes disconnects for no reason.

Comment: @TravisHintz define "disconnects". An EOF? an exception? or...? But: fun fact - sockets do indeed break occasionally.

Comment: Hard to explain, but runs through all the reading just fine and it will handle the data just fine like it should. It's just, as it is running and the server and client are talking to each other, the socket will just become disconnected with no errors. It can be playing with the data and putting it to a new array and the sockets will give out.

Comment: @TravisHintz so how does that manifest: do you simply never get the async callback? or does it come into your method?

Comment: I put my code into your code and for rid of the syncs. Here's a quick run down.. I start the server, start the client and they connect and are both waiting for data. I send login info over the network stream from the client to the server and it enters you code. bytesread equals 1 and goes into my code. While the server is reading the network stream or just working with the incoming data the socket just disconnects at different times and my data will still be working and going into my handlers sub and then server application suddenly closes with no errors thrown.

Comment: However if it can make through the data and handler sub before the socket randomly closes bit will send data to the client of player info and then the client will crash due to the socket being disconnected.